# .NET user interface components recommendations

Tags: asp.net, uicomponents

I'm looking for advice on what .NET user interface components are out there on the market. I have been developing asp.net websites and have mainly been using the Visual studio toolbox  build in controls supported by the AjaxcontrolToolkit and the applications have been mainly used inhouse running on our company intranet.

But now a new client wants a much more professional looking, commercial web application and they have a budget for some user components for use in the application. Any recommendations where value for money will be realised.

Interested in components that will integrate well with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 or even .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.Net (but not WinForms), I've been pretty happy with Telerik.

[If you get 10,000 reputation here, you can even get it free.](http://www.telerik.com/registration-login/stackoverflowregistration.aspx)

Comment: Woah, really? 10k? Crap! What am I waiting for?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/) and also [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/). Both companies offer industry-grade components which beautifully extend ASP.NET and AJAX functionality.